# How do you add a layer to an existing Yocto build?

Tags: yocto

I have a Yocto build given to me. There's a `meta-coolthing.git` directory I want to add to my build. If I look in my project's `layers/` directory, it doesn't show up there, so I think that means it's not in the build. Where do I go to add `meta-coolthing` to my Yocto build?

Kind of a simple question, but that's all there is to it. It's hard to get your bearings again in Yocto if you've been away for awhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I think [the simple answer](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#enabling-your-layer) is to add it to the bottom of the `BBLAYERS` variable in `./build/conf/bblayers.conf`.

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
... bunches of existing layers
   /path/to/project/layers/meta-already-here \
   /path/to/project/layers/meta-coolthing \
   "
```

And re-run bitbake inside the environment wrapper thing.

Initially that failed since it couldn't find `meta-coolthing` at that path. I had to git clone the project from the mirror `meta-coolthing.git` directory I already had into the project directory:

```
cd /path/to/project/layers
git clone ../../mirror/meta-coolthing.git -b main
```

Choosing an arbitrary branch to start with.

Comment: Yes. It's also documented in the official manual.